# JNDI lookup in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic

I have a legacy code with JNDI template which is:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${java.naming.factory.initial}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${java.naming.provider.url}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and `java.naming.factory.initial` is `weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory` and `java.naming.provider.url` is `t3://localhost:7001`.
In weblogic `10.3.6.0` everything work fine, but in weblogic `12.2.1.3.0` I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
```

Here is an exert of classpath:

```
CLASSPATH=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_1\lib\tools.jar;D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;
```

Comment: do you use spring ?

Comment: @PiotrRogowski Sure I do.

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic server 12c brings some change in its classpath. The class weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory is located under D:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\wlthint3client.jar

weblogic.jar is now "manifest only" and should not be used on the client side.